# django reading file from root: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, path

Django 1.9:

I am trying to open and read a file in a views.py function. I am getting a FileNotFound error, however I think the path is correct. 
I have put the file in the root:

```
C:.
|   file1.txt
|   settings.py
|   urls.py
|   wsgi.py
|   __init__.py
|
```

I have the following in my settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

In my views I am trying to open the file with the following line:

```
def post(self, request):
        file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'file1.txt'))
```

But this error occurs:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\x\\y\\z\\Year 4\\Semester 2\\cvCleaner\\cvcleaner\\file1.txt'
```

Is it to do with having spaces in my directory names? I'm not sure.

Comment: can you post the path where you put the file ?

Comment: As I was posting the path for you, I realized it was not in the correct dir. My bad. Thanks for responding so quickly though. Mods can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My embarrassment might save someone in the future:

The path was in fact wrong.

I had the file in the same path as `settings.py`, moving it to the same path as `manage.py` works fine.